# Continuation token specified in the request is malformed / Invalid format for continuation token Azure Cosmos DB pagination

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am facing an issue with the implementation of paging in cosmos database using continuation token. First time I am getting first batch of results with continuation token in JSON format, but when I pass back that same token JSON string to cosmos DB for getting next set of results, sometimes it throws "Continuation token specified in the request is malformed" or sometimes "Invalid format for continuation token".

Here is the code -

```
        QueryRequestOptions queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions
        {
            MaxItemCount = pageSize
        };

        try
        {
            using (FeedIterator<TOutputDocument> resultSetIterator = _cosmosContainer.GetItemQueryIterator<TOutputDocument>(queryDefinition, continuationToken, queryRequestOptions))
            {
                if (resultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    FeedResponse<TOutputDocument> response = await resultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();

                    if (response == null)


                    {
                        throw new NullReferenceException($"Unable to get response from cosmos db against query - {query}, container - {nameof(_cosmosContainer)}");
                    }
                    continuationToken = response.ContinuationToken;
                    documents.AddRange(response);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex)
        { }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add the continuationToken in the question?

Comment: 2 possible scenarios: Either you are using the continuation token in a different query or you might be sending that continuation token somewhere else (maybe through a Web API) and when it comes back, it is wrongly encoded. Like https://stackoverflow.com/q/66995110/5641598

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error denotes , it seems that the continuation token is null or in invalid format.

If the token is Null,

```
[{\"token\":null,\"range\":{\"min\":\"05C1DFFFFFFFFC\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}]
```

Follow the steps mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1364#issuecomment-614230989).

In the case of Invalid token, Try to encode it with Base64 as below

```
string continuationToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cosmosToken));
```

Comment: Had to encode token and decode while passing back to Cosmos db. Thanks much @sajeetharan.